# Docker-ce vs Docker.io for Ubuntu 19.04 / Disco

Tags: 19.04, docker

I have

```
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

Linux work01 5.0.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 17:41:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to install Docker-ce, did try to use [Docker official doc](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

Tried **INSTALL DOCKER CE**

BUT find docker-ce returned Emply

```
sudo apt search docker-ce
```

After tryed **Install from a package** downloaded containerd.io_1.2.5-1_amd64.deb and tried to install

```
sudo dpkg -i containerd.io_1.2.5-1_amd64.deb
```

BUT go new try didn't found docker-ce package.

What variant I can use, except that install docker.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages for Disco (19.04) aren't yet available, which is why the documentation doesn't mention 19.04 as supported (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#os-requirements).
This can also be seen when you compare the packages for Cosmic (https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/pool/edge/amd64/) to the packages for disco (https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/disco/pool/edge/amd64/).  You can see the Docker packages aren't there yet.

However, there is a snap provided by Canonical you can try (https://snapcraft.io/docker).  This can be installed with `sudo snap install docker`.

Update: There are now nightly packages (https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/disco/pool/nightly/amd64/) available. See https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/533. There they mention when Docker CE 19.03.0 is released, stable packages will be available for Disco.

Comment: Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
can't be better?

Comment: The latest edge version for 18.04 (Bionic) (LTS) and 18.10 (Cosmic) from the Docker repos is 18.09.6.  But it does appear that the latest edge snap is  18.06.1-ce, yes.